# How to get a pdf file from an url ( which has pdf ) and serve it to my client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

This is my code to fetch a `pdf` from the mentioned `uri` :

```
app.route("/downloadpdf").get(function(req,res){

    var requestParameter = {
        uri: "http://www.nitdgp.ac.in/career17/Revised%20advertisement%20for%20faculty.pdf",
        method: "GET",
        headers : {
            'content-type' : 'application/pdf'
        }
    }
    console.log(requestParameter.uri);
    request(requestParameter, function(error, response, body) {
        var buf = Buffer.from(body,'base64');
        res.type('pdf').send(buf);
    });
})
```

Comment: Please mention the issue that you have with this code.

Comment: The file which is being fetched is getting corrupted.

Comment: Use a 303 redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the encoding to *null* in the request to ensure you're downloading binary content:

```
app.route("/downloadpdf").get(function(req,res){

    var requestParameter = {
        uri: "http://www.nitdgp.ac.in/career17/Revised%20advertisement%20for%20faculty.pdf",
        method: "GET",
        headers : {
            'content-type' : 'application/pdf'
        },
        encoding: null
    }

    // The body will be a Buffer object
    request(requestParameter, function(error, response, body) {
        res.type('pdf').send(body);
    });
})
```

From the Request docs:

- encoding - encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). **(Note: if you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)**

Comment: Great, glad to be of help!